# Can't insert values to my table inside anonymous block..but it is working if i run the query without begin end

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO  mtl_strmnth_grid_tmp
( guid,
  rigmove_mnth_no,
  rigmove_month,
  AVERAGE,
  actual
)
SELECT
    '1234',
    A.rigmove_mnth_no,
    A.rigmove_month,
    B.AVG as "AVERAGE",
    b.actual AS "ACTUAL"
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            to_char(quarter_date,'MM') AS rigmove_mnth_no,
            to_char(quarter_date,'MONTH') AS rigmove_month
        FROM
            t_adm_calendar
        WHERE
            quarter_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
    ) A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            rigmove_mnth_no,
            rigmove_month,
            SUM(AVG) AS AVG,
            actual
        FROM
            (SELECT
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sm1.rigmove_date) rigmove_mnth_no,
                    to_char(sm1.rigmove_date,'MONTH') rigmove_month,
                    SUM(DISTINCT sm2.AVG) AS AVG,
                    sm1.main_activity_code_pk,
                    SUM(sm1.actual) AS actual
                FROM
                    v_report_smdelivery sm1
                    LEFT JOIN v_report_smdelivery_budget sm2 ON sm1.main_activity_code_pk = sm2.main_activity_code_pk
                WHERE
                    sm1.rigmove_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('31/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
                GROUP BY
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sm1.rigmove_date),
                    to_char(sm1.rigmove_date,'MONTH'),
                    sm1.main_activity_code_pk
                ORDER BY
                    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sm1.rigmove_date),
                    to_char(sm1.rigmove_date,'MONTH')
            )
        GROUP BY
            rigmove_mnth_no,
            rigmove_month,
            actual

        ORDER BY
            rigmove_mnth_no,
            rigmove_month
    ) b ON A.rigmove_mnth_no = b.rigmove_mnth_no
ORDER BY rigmove_mnth_no
;
```

If i use this query inside begin end/..it is showing error
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-06512: at line 3
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:
*Action:

But if I run this query outside plsql block it is working...help me to solve this....

Comment: Which version and patch level of Oracle are you using? It's possible you're hitting a bug - there are a few around that error. It probably isn't related to the insert - do you still see it if you use that query part in a cursor and loop through the results? Your query can probably be simplified though - I'd start by taking out all the `order by` clauses, which aren't useful, and might be related to a bug; and you could probably remove the subquery with a bit of rework.

Comment: Thankyou now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I removed the extract in group by clause and it is working fine...

But another system it is working fine even though extract in group by clause...